# Moments and bridges

Tags: classical-mechanics

The horizontal roadways of a bridge AB, 12 m long, weight 56000 N and rests on two supports at its ends, What is the pressure on each support when a lorry of weight 33600 N, Starting from A, is at a point two- third of the on the bridge?

And my point is how we will find the pressure ,after finding the force which is moment/distance because for pressure u need area.

Comment: Without knowing the area of each support you can't find the pressure. I'm guessing the question really means find the force on each support.

Comment: take moments from either end at the supports